# How to Install RStudio using Nix?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm fairly new to Nix and migrating from Homebrew. So far I've been able to install quite a bit using:

```
nix-env -q
nix-env -i
nix-channel --update
nix-env -u
nix-collect-garbage
```

However, I have not been able to successfully install RStudio. I'd appreciate help in understanding why I've been able to install neovim and emacs with `nix-env -i` but I can't do the same with RStudio. I'd also appreciate help in understanding how I may/should install RStudio and other similar packages. Thanks.

**Update:**
The specific commands I tried and the resulting error messages follow.

Attempt #1

```
nix-env -i RStudio
```

Attempt #2

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.rstudioWrapper
```

Error returned for both attempts:

```
installing ‘RStudio-1.2.1335-wrapper’
error: Package ‘RStudio-1.2.1335’ in /nix/store/25q78bckai9szsc5wv5ndr10c4b1wghv-nixpkgs-20.03pre207249.7e8454fb856/nixpkgs/pkgs/applications/editors/rstudio/default.nix:128 is not supported on ‘x86_64-darwin’, refusing to evaluate.

a) For nixos-rebuild you can set
{ nixpkgs.config.allowUnsupportedSystem = true; }
in configuration.nix to override this.

b) For nix-env, nix-build, nix-shell or any other Nix command you can add
{ allowUnsupportedSystem = true; }
to ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix.
```

Comment: I created a file 'default.nix' with the following content:  `{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } } : pkgs.mkShell {
    buildInputs = [
        pkgs.rstudio
    ] ;
}` and ran `nix-shell`.  I think this did not work for me because I am running on a MacBookPro, but it might work for you.

Comment: How about you show us exactly what command you ran and the full output from it, including any error messages?  I don't know much about RStudio but your error message might be similar to one I've fixed before in other contexts.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I added the commands I ran and the resulting error messages. Apparently, there is an issue with MacOS/Darwin.

Comment: @Ari based on your edited text, I think you need to create a file name '~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix' (create said directories if necessary) with content `{ allowUnsupportedSystem = true; }`   You may/may not run into different issues, but this issue is easily fixable.

Comment: @Ari I think after you fix this issue you will run into another issue because I also have MacOS/Darwin and was unable to install.  I will try it on my linux box when I get a chance.